# jQuery addClass is not working now

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So I'm trying to add a class with jquery.
Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').addClass('scrollbar-dynamic');
});
```

I can confirm the script is loaded on frontend as it appears in source code.
Plus all other javascript "1400 lines" works fine.
The addClass jquery method is also used about 30 more times throughout the script.
I'm also using the latest version of wordpress
It's just this time it's not working.
Here is a working [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjvwwz9r/)

Stuff like this just drives me crazy.
Cheers for the help

Comment: in that fiddle the classes are being added, right?

Comment: addClass() is working properly in fiddle

Comment: It's possible Wordpress is loading JQuery in noConflict mode or that it's aliased, by the theme or by a plugin; try adding `console.log(jQuery);` above your code and see what shows up in the browser's developer tools console. If it's `undefined` or something similar, JQuery may be aliased to something different.

Comment: The code in your fiddle works correctly. Please divide and conquer to isolate the problem, and then update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I ran your fiddle and the class gets assigned fine. Here's the screenshot on the inspector. Are you seeing any other error in your browser console log? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKis6.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKis6.jpg)

Comment: @JVLobo yeah classes are being added, forgot to save fiddle. its updated now :/

Comment: still working well @WebDevGuy

Comment: @jack this shows up in browser console. function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}

Comment: @JVLobo this is the problem. it works fine in jsfiddle, works fine when used many other times on the website im developing. But not working for this occasion. It's bizarre it works and doesn't work in the same script.

Comment: try clearing your browser cache @Web Dev Guy

Comment: so that fiddle doesn't provide us any information about your problem... it's just a regular jQuery addClass code

Comment: any clues (i.e. errors) in the browser **developer** tools console? try adding `console.log(document.body.classList)` after the point where you `addClass` ... if the console shows that `scrollbar-dynamic` is part of body classList, perhaps some other code is removing the class?

Comment: Omg I'm such a doofus sometimes. Of course I can't see it when I view source code. jquery modifies the source code so it wont show up when I view page source. Needed to look in the dev tools element inspector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok - since `console.log(jQuery)` is returning what we'd expect, I think the issue is with how the library is being referenced. Here's your code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('body').addClass('scrollbar-dynamic');
});
```

The script knows what jQuery is...but it doesn't seem to know what `$` is, and it's not being bound to anything when it's called.

Try this - if it works, it's a binding issue.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('body').addClass('scrollbar-dynamic');
});
```

Comment: Omg I'm such a doofus sometimes. Of course I can't see it when I view source code. jquery modifies the source code so it wont show up when I view page source. Needed to look in the dev tools element inspector.